# Ubuntu not booting up afterwards unebootin application to boot without cd/usb

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

First I get this page and after at one voilet blank screen appears and nothing else shows

Then I tried to modify from grub command by changing root (hd0,1) and prefix to (hd0,1)/boot/grub. No progress

Further more added some more commands chainloader +1.
Insmod Linux
Insmod normal
Normal still no progress.

After that I decided to install new copy of Linux/windows from cd but boot menu won't allow me to change the boot priority. It showing settings save f10 in boot menu but after rebooting it's same.

Please help !!

Regards
Mukesh

Comment: This site won't allow to upload images asking for 10 reputation

Comment: try uploading images now

Comment: Still unable to upload give a test mail on mukesh.tiwari.9810@gmail.com I will share images